# Material-ui v4 select component not working with leaflet-sidebar

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, material-ui

I've encountered an issue whereby the select component of material-ui v4 doesnt display the dropdown when its placed inside the leaflet map sidebar component. However the select dropdown works outside on its own.

I've also tested and found that using material v3 doesn't present this issue.

I've linked the codesandbox below, would appreciate any help into this matter. Thank you!

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-40c6l?file=/mapview.js

Comment: Something is intercepting mouse down events and preventing them from reaching the Select. Click events are reaching the Select, but mouse down events aren't reaching the Select or the containing divs and v4 changed the open of the items from being triggered on click to being triggered on mouse down. After clicking on it (which successfully gives it focus), you can press the down arrow key and see it successfully open.